# I need help with refining my string formatter

Tags: c#

I am trying to format  strings  depending on the type ...but I feel it's kind of ugly. has anyone have any sugestions for a more refined approch?

```
 string DateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy";
 string NumberFormat = "0.0";

string FormatString(Type t, object value)
    {
        string output = "";

        switch (t.Name.ToUpper())
        {

            case "DATETIME":
                output = ((DateTime)value).ToString(DateFormat);
                break;
            case "SINGLE":
                output = ((Single)value).ToString(NumberFormat);
                break;
            case "DOUBLE":
                output = ((Double)value).ToString(NumberFormat);
                break;
            default:
                output = value.ToString();
                break;
        }

        return output;

    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to just set the formats on the CurrentCulture and let the formatters deal with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just overloading methods?

```
using System;

namespace test {

    static class Formatter {

        const string DateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy";
        const string NumberFormat = "0.0";

        public static string Format(double d) {
            return d.ToString(NumberFormat);
        }

        public static string Format(DateTime d) {
            return d.ToString(DateFormat);
        }

        // most generic method
        public static string Format(object o) {
            return o.ToString();
        }

    }

    class Program {

        public static void Main() {
            Console.WriteLine(Formatter.Format(2.0d));
            Console.WriteLine(Formatter.Format(DateTime.Now));
            // an integer => no specific function defined => pick the
            // most generic overload (object)
            Console.WriteLine(Formatter.Format(4));
        }

    }
}
```

**NOTE**: if you need to compare types, you should use

```
if (typeof(int) == t){
    // ...
}
```

and not perform comparisons on the type name (or at least, if you do it, check the **fully qualified** type names, i.e. including the namespace).

**EDIT**
An alternative solution, that takes into account Allon's comment, using a dictionary type->function:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace test {

    public class Formatter {

        delegate string FormatFunction(object o);

        private string FormatDouble(object o) {
            double d = (double)o;
            return d.ToString("0.0");
        }

        private string FormatDateTime(object o) {
            DateTime d = (DateTime)o;
            return d.ToString("MMM dd yyyy");
        }

        // map types to format function
        private Dictionary<Type, FormatFunction> _formatters = new Dictionary<Type, FormatFunction>();

        public Formatter() {
            _formatters.Add(typeof(double), FormatDouble);
            _formatters.Add(typeof(DateTime), FormatDateTime);
        }

        public string Format(object o) { 
            Type t = o.GetType();
            if (_formatters.ContainsKey(t)){
                return _formatters[t](o);
            } else {
                return o.ToString();
            }
        }

    }

    class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            Formatter f = new Formatter();
            Console.WriteLine(f.Format(2.0d));
            Console.WriteLine(f.Format(DateTime.Now));
            Console.WriteLine(f.Format(4));
        }
    }
}
```

With this second solution, you get the correct function even if you just have a reference to an object (I still would use the first solution if possible).

Comment: I like this option even better than my generic solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, the nicest comment I ever received :)

Comment: Pretty good, though this won't work if the caller to this method is only holding an object reference to whatever needs to be ToString-ed. E.g. void PrintDebugVar(string name, object var) { Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", name, Formatter.Format(var))); }

Comment: Oh, and one more thing - your statically typed solution would be even more elegant using Extension Methods, and would require adding just a single keyword to each method (and will even work in .NET 2.0 if using VS2008 with a slight nudge).

Answer (score 2):

```
string Format<T>(T value)
{
    Type[] numericTypes = new Type[] {typeof(double), typeof(single)};

    if (Array.IndexOf(numericTypes, typeof(T)))
        return string.Format("{0:0.0}", value);
    else if (typeof(T) is DateTime)
        return string.Format("{0:MMM dd yyyy}", value);
    else
        return value.ToString();
}
```

If you're using .Net 3.0 or later I can make that even a little nicer.

Comment: I believe you meant .NET 2.0 or later (i.e. Generics).

Comment: You were just dying to sprinkle a little linq in there, right? ;-)

Comment: `typeof(T) is DateTime` will always be false, didn't you mean `T is DateTime` or `typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime)` ?

Comment: Oops, yeah: actually what I want is: `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DateTime))`.  But it's moot: overloading the method is better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The two other solutions provided here are great if you need to invoke the proper formatting according to the static type of the supplied argument. But if you need to perform formatting according to the runtime type of an object, they won't work. Your original attempt was good, but comparing types in that way is not the best way. Instead, use the 'is' keyword:

```
public static string FormatObject(object obj)
{
    if (obj is DateTime)
        return ((DateTime)obj).ToString("MMM dd yyyy");
    else if (obj is float || obj is double)
        return (obj as IFormattable).ToString("0.0", new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo());
    else return obj.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Actually the second solution I provided does formatting according to the runtime type of an object... what's wrong with that?

Comment: Well yeah, your edited solution does check the runtime type. But look at it - apart from the fact that it is rather large and convoluted (just because you insist on using method overloads), it uses reflection (.GetType()) which is expensive and it stores and maintains shared state which is not thread safe, frugal or even sane for such a simple problem. If I'd encounter something like that in code, it would take me a few minutes to just realize what it does, and then I'd rewrite it like my solution for maintainability and readability's sake.

Comment: Oops, forgot to include this link about reflection vs. 'is' keyword performance: http://gabewishnie.blogspot.com/2005/10/is-and-as-lesser-known-c-keywords.html

Comment: I don't think it's convoluted, it's just a map of function pointers; and by the way, the methods are not overloaded. Also, I don't think that a GetType will affect performance... and sincerely, the link you provided proves nothing. But in any case, of course your solution works.

Comment: I think that a one-page solution is convoluted (or 'over-engineered' if you'd like) when compared to a 6 line solution that does the exact same thing, while being more readable and maintainable.